# Prevent windows from moving when display sleeps on Wayland

Tags: gnome, display, multi-monitor, wayland

I am using GNOME with Wayland, on openSUSE Tumbleweed, and an AMD GPU if relevant.

I have multiple displays connected to my computer, including my TV via HDMI.

The issue I am trying to resolve is that ~10-15 minutes after turning off the TV the computer thinks it has disconnected and moves any windows that were on it, whereas I would prefer those windows open / stay on that display -- even if it isn't "connected".

At first the TV would be seen as completely disconnected, and no longer show up in System settings -> Displays. I went through the available settings on the TV and disabled power saving and enabled "fast startup", and now after the ~10-15 minute delay the displays briefly flash however the display is still listed in the settings -- unfortunately this brief moment is enough for any windows to be moved off that display.

I am aware that this should be doable on X11, possibly by using [xorg configuration files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/multihead#Configuration_using_xorg.conf). I would like however to get this working with Wayland if at all possible -- even better if it can be done while allowing the TV to enter power saving, and just never "forget" this display even when disconnected. Disabling automatic screen detection entirely would also be acceptable, though I haven't found any information on how to do so with GNOME/Wayland.